# Any way to align an entity to all axises in minecraft bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to summon an object and then center it in Minecraft Bedrock Edition. I am trying to just make the coordinate the exact position (eg. 10.0 80.0 10.0 or teleporting to 10 80 10). I have tried to use a function to teleport it by 0.01 until it detects a new block, then teleports to it's centered coordinate, it works sometimes, but it also sometimes doesn't go to the correct cord, or goes on forever teleporting away. I do not have an exact cord that I am teleporting it to so that would not help.

Comment: So basically you want to use the /summon when you are flying at a random location in creative and then make sure that entity summons aligned to a block?

Comment: @A.Shetye Yes basically

Comment: For anyone who doesn't understand, basically make `~ ~ ~` be say `5 10 5` and not `5.283 10.2 5.3955`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways you could do this. The first is to just summon the entity at the correct place, as everyone else has been telling you (I will use a sheep for the remainder of this)

```
/summon sheep 23 24 25
```

instead of

```
/summon sheep ~ ~ ~
```

The other way you could do it is to take advantage of a shulker's auto-align feature. You can summon a shulker, it will align automatically to the axis'. You can then execute as the shulker, and summon a sheep at it. Example:

```
/execute @e[type=shulker,c=1] ~ ~ ~ summon sheep
```

After this, you just kill the shulker.

Comment: If this is the best that comes up for a few days I'll give you the bounty

Answer (score -2):

/summon entity 10 80 10 **or** /teleport @e[type=entity] 10 80 10 **or teleport it by 0.5/1.0**

Comment: Some context would help. Is this supposed to be one chained command, three commands that are all necessary, or just a list of commands to try until the asker gets the effect they want? Right now, this answer is confusing and unclear.